# why does present perfect sometimes fit with simple past and sometimes not

Tags: meaning

3: He decided that he had had enough and now he regretted it
(where Present Perfect he **has had enough** is **invalid in conjunction with Simple Past regretted)**

but in a song of Lou Reed "Pale Blue Eyes" I found this " I thought of you as everything I'**ve had** but **could not keep**," we have also a present perfect with a simple past, why in one case it is possible (my example) and not in Lecelot's example. Is it because regretted does not imply a single moment

I really don't understand the difference between these 2 examples

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are completely different, because one of them has a "that" clause (reported speech) and the other doesn't.

Normally when you have a clause as the object of a verb like *say* or *think*, you follow the "sequence of the tenses": so if the verb would be present, it becomes past:

> He thinks "I am lucky" -> He thought he was lucky.

and a present perfect becomes a past perfect:

> He thinks "I have finished" -> He thought he had finished.

(Even in this construction we can sometimes use the present for a state that is still continuing, eg "I didn't know that you live/lived there")

Your second example is not *I thought that you were ...* but the completely different structure *I thought of you as ...* There is no "sequences of tenses", and any tense is possible in this construction:

> I thought of you as everything I have.
>
> I thought of you as everything I had.
>
> I thought of you as everything I have had.
>
> I thought of you as everything I will have.

Comment: if I understand your answer correctly that is because one is reported speech so decided past simple can't fit with with present perfect have had, so it is not because 
" have had enough is invalid in conjunction with Simple Past DECIDED not regretted)" regretted is not in the reported speech. Am I right ?

Comment: The past _decided_ makes it likely that _had had_ and _regretted_ are past, but it doesn't force that. With suitable context, several combinations of present/present perfect and past/past perfect are possible: _that he has had enough and now he regrets it_; _that he had had enough and now he regrets it_; _that he had had enough and now he regretted it_. These indicate that his state of having had enough and/or his regret last to the present. The only one I can't find a plausible context for is _that  he has had enough and now he regretted it_.

Comment: I think I still understand why the last one is not possible is it still a problem of reported speech , I don't think so because you have written  he decided that he has had enough and now he regrets is valid  and in this case has had  is not backshifted

Comment: Sorry, @user5577, I'm not sure what you're asking. If the circumstances reported still hold now, then we have the option of not backshifting.

Comment: Got it now !In fact what I did not understand at the time was that if there were  no backshifting, the feeling of having enough was still valid so in any case it could  be "regretted "